# Puprlish Material with Blue Voronoi Cracks

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials

Is there a way to make a shader (puprlish Material with blue, reflective Voronoi Cracks) from the following picture?

[image]

Comment: as you say, use a Voronoi as a factor in a Mix shader between the 2 materials, Glossy and non-Glossy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Voronoi to mix between two shaders.

[image]

One seems to have a slight translucency effect while the other is opaque and glossy.

Use the same Voronoi to bump the shaders.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Duarte! I am going to use the *node configs* for a project.